# Cartoon series where 2 boys and 1 girl summon monsters ( NOT MAGI NATION OR HUNTIK )

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the name of a show I used to watch as a kid several years ago. It was about a boy with black hair ( I believe he was of Asian descent and was able to create/summon monsters with the use of his notepad ) whose father is dead. He becomes friends with a tech-savvy black kid and a rich white girl ( If it helps to narrow it down any further, there was this episode involving the rich girl where her father named a boat either after her or dead mother ). I know the premise of the show was that they were able to summon monsters and that there was an evil group they were fighting against. I've looked up Magi-Nation, and while both are similar, its not the same series I was talking about. Thank you!

Comment: How many years are "several years" to you? To a 22-years-old, 8 years will probably qualify as "several", while a 45-years-old would call 20+ years "several" and a mere 8 years would be "a few"

Answer (score 1):

Is this [Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Kaijudo:_Rise_of_the_Duel_Masters)?

The main character, [Ray](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Raiden_Pierce-Okamoto), lives with his [grandfather](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Raiden_Okamoto) and [mother](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Janet_Pierce-Okamoto) and he is Asian/white.

Here is a clip in which you can see the rich blonde friend and black friend:

(This answer was mostly copied from my other answer.)